# proving Fermat's theorem on $p = x^2 + 3y^2$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Here is a modern proof from the notes [primes presented by quadratic forms](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Stevenhagen-Primes.pdf).  We are interested in $p = x^2 + 3y^2$ so we would like to have something like:

$$ p = (x + y\sqrt{-3})(x - y\sqrt{-3}) = x^2 + 3y^2 $$

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i /3}$ be the cube root of unity, then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] \subset \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a subring.

In that bigger space, $p$ should factor as well:

$$ p = (x + \omega y)(x + \omega^2 y) = x^2 - xy + y^2 = (x - y/2)^2 + (3/4)y^2 \tag{1}$$

Let $\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{Z} + \omega \mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).  Using modular arithmetic in this ring we can get a finite field and group of units

$$ (\mathcal{O}/2\mathcal{O})^\times = \langle \omega \rangle \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, +) \tag{2}$$

The author concludes $y$ is even, $x + \omega y$ is "congruent to $1$" possibly mod $2$.

Finally I don't see how $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] = \mathbb{Z} + 2 \mathcal{O}$ leads to his

$$ p = x^2 + 3y^2 \text{ iff } p \equiv 1 \mod 3 $$

I certanly don't see how this demonstrates the *existence* of $x,y$ given that $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $p\equiv x^{2} \mod{3}$